# Showing that $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am working on a problem and I have the weak formulation of Poisson's problem in $2$ spatial dimensions i.e. $u = u(x,y)$:
$$a(u,v) = \ell(v) $$
where
$$a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\nabla v\quad\text{ and }\quad \ell(v) = \int_\Omega fv.$$
I have the following Sobolev space

$$\mathcal{H}_0^1(\Omega) = \left\{f:\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}\,\bigg| 
\int_\Omega |f|^2<\infty,\,
\int_\Omega \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|^2<\infty\,,
\int_\Omega \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|^2<\infty\,,
f(\partial\Omega) = 0
\right\} $$
which I have equipped with the following norm
$$\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_0^1} = \left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\|_2+\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right\|_2 $$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the usual $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega)$-norm.

**Now for my problem**: I wanted to use [Lax-Milgram theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation#The_Lax.E2.80.93Milgram_theorem) to show existence of solutions to the weak formulation, however I am unable to show that $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ is coercive, i.e.

$$a(u,u)\geq \alpha\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_0^1}^2 $$
and I even suspect that it in fact isn't coercive.

**Question:** Is $a(\cdot,\cdot)$ coercive (with respect to the norm I have chosen)? If so, how do I show it?

**Attempt:** We have that
$$a(u,u) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 = \int_\Omega \left[\left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|^2 + \left|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|^2\right] = \left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\|_2^2+\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right\|_2^2$$
and 
$$\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_0^1}^2 = \left(\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\|_2+\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right\|_2\right)^2 >\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\|_2^2+\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right\|_2^2 = a(u,u)$$
hence I believe that $a(u,u)< \|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_0^1}^2$, so the only chance seems to find $\alpha>0$ little enough, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for each non-negative $a$ and $b$, $(a+b)^2\leqslant 2a^2+2b^2$, we have $$\|u\|_{\mathcal{H}_0^1}^2 = \left(\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\|_2+\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right\|_2 \right)^2\leqslant 2\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right\|_2^2+2\left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right\|_2^2=2\cdot a(u,u),$$
hence $\alpha=1/2$ does the job.

Comment: (+1) How does one prove that inequality? Or am  I just brain-farting and it's completely obvious?

Comment: I figured it out. It comes from the root-mean-square, arithmetic mean inequality.